# jquery and wordpress does't work

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to load a jquery function to my wordpress

here is what I did

in function.php added the below code

```
function my_city_script() {         
    wp_enqueue_script( 'city-script', '/cities.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_city_script' );
```

my cities.JS file as below

```
(function($) {
$("#sel_State").change(function() {
  $("#sel_City").load("load_cities.php?choice=" + $("#sel_State").val());
})

})( jQuery );
```

and to a page inside my wordpress coded as below

```
<select id="sel_State" name="sel_State" aria-labelledby="State-ariaLabel" class="required" title="State. *">
      <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
      <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
       ... etc
</select>
<select id="sel_City" name="sel_City" class="required" title="City. *">
</select>
```

beside a php file to load cities as below

```
include '../DBConfig.php';
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
$sql = "SELECT distinct city FROM zy_virtualuser WHERE state ='$choice' order by city"; 

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option>" . $row['city'] . "</option>";
    }
} 

$conn->close();
```

everything works perfectly outside wordpress, but in wordpress 2 issues faced
1- nothing on change event loaded to cities.
2- it's very slow to load when change to any state.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have included the jQuery twice.

Also you can remove true from `wp_enqueue_script` and check the jQuery conflict. Also change the version number.

```
function my_city_script() {         
    wp_enqueue_script( 'city-script', '/cities.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1.1);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_city_script' );
```

Comment: For slow issue, yes I embedded the code twice by wrong, and still dig why the code doesn't work

Comment: Can you add and try jQuery.noConflict() at top in cities.JS and try?

Comment: I added the statement to the top as you mentioned, but still not working

Comment: Can you provide me link of the site so that I can check it?

Comment: can you try this in cities.js ,

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  jQuery("#sel_State").change(function() {
   jQuery("#sel_City").load("load_cities.php?choice=" + jQuery("#sel_State").val());
  });
 });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146885/discussion-between-peter-elias-and-ahmed-ginani).